# MySQL: Sometimes query failed to use index

Tags: mysql-5.1

I have a complex query including join of 4-5 tables. 1 months back, I have optimized this query and it was using the index. Also, `two months back, index of all tables had been rebuilt by just export and import the database`. Just few days back, I found that this query is appearing in slow query logs again. When I analysed it, I found that one table in this query is not using index which prompts to higher join size as well as higher execution time.

As a solution, I executed `optimized table tablename` command on the table which was skipping the index. As a result Query again started to use that index and not appearing in slow query log.

Now, I have below question regarding the above analysis:

- Why query skipped to use the index?
- Should I rebuild the index after interval of each two months either by executing Optimize command or    by export / import?
- As we know that after each insert, index rebuild then why this issue occur? Is it the result of fragmentation?

Below is the explain result of query after optimization of the jos_content tbale:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: jtrf
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_name_jos_tag_rules_fields
          key: idx_name_jos_tag_rules_fields
      key_len: 767
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: jtrv
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_field_id_jos_tag_rules_values
          key: idx_field_id_jos_tag_rules_values
      key_len: 4
          ref: jprod.jtrf.id
         rows: 16
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: jct
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_content_id_jos_content_tags,idx_tag_value_id_jos_
ent_tags
          key: idx_tag_value_id_jos_content_tags
      key_len: 4
          ref: jprod.jtrv.id
         rows: 411
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: a
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_access,idx_id_jos_content
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: jprod.jct.content_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: u
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: jprod.a.created_by
         rows: 1
        Extra:
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: g
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 1
          ref: jprod.a.access
         rows: 1
        Extra:
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 7
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: jos_tag_rules_content_exclude
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: jprod.a.id,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 8. row ***************************
           id: 6
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: inc
         type: index_subquery
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using where
*************************** 9. row ***************************
           id: 5
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: jos_tag_rules_content_include
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: jprod.a.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 10. row ***************************
           id: 4
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: inc
         type: index_subquery
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using where
*************************** 11. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: exc
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 12. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DEPENDENT UNION
        table: inc
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 13. row ***************************
           id: NULL
  select_type: UNION RESULT
        table: <union2,3>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: NULL
        Extra:
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You could add the query and the `EXPLAIN` plans (both of them, using/not using the index.)